# Make clickable div heading rearrange to be responsive on smaller widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I have a question about using clickable divs to display text/content in the area of below the divs. The content is displayed upon clicking the div underneath the row of divs.

Please see the layout in the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4fwwevaf/

The question is:

How can I have the div buttons above rearrange themselves on a smaller device/smaller window. Specifically, I want the tabs to rearrange themselves such that the appropriate content is show underneath each tab heading such as:

```
<div class="tabBox-3">Tab 1</div>
<div class="divText" id="div1">
    <h1>Tab 1 content</h1>
    <p>Tab 1 content text</p>
</div>

<div class="tabBox-3">Tab 2</div>
<div class="divText" id="div2">
    <h1>Tab 2 content</h1>
    <p>Tab 2 content text</p>
</div>

<div class="tabBox-3">Tab 3</div>
<div class="divText" id="div3">
    <h1>Tab 3 content</h1>
    <p>Tab 3 content text</p>
</div>
```

or as shown in the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1je8p38/

Is there a way to do this type of effect? Or is my entire approach terrible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the @media rule for CSS3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am familiar with @media queries to a certain extent, but not sure how to use them to produce the pattern specified in my post/fiddles (specifically going from the first fiddle to the layout of the second one)

Comment: @nonForMe The first fiddle has hidden/shown functionality. The 2nd doesn't. You want it like that? Avoiding the hide/show functionality on smaller screens?

Comment: Well, I was ultimately going to have an accordion type layout on the smaller screen. Ignored that for the simplicity to of the question.

To answer more plainly: I do not want the hide/show functionality on the smaller screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to also add the tabs inside the divText div's, defaulting them to hidden until you want it to switch to the other view.  Then hiding the original tabs.

The CSS could be something like this...

```
.divText .tabBox-3{display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.tabBox-3{
  width:100%;
}

.tabRow{
  display:none;
 }

.divText>.tabBox-3{
  display:block;
 }

.divText{
  display:block !important;
 }
```

}

Then your divText blocks would be like this...

```
  <div class="divText" id="div1">
      <div class="tabBox-3">
        Tab 1
      </div>
      <h1> Div 1 content</h1>
      <p> div 1 content text</p>
  </div>
```

See my fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/4fwwevaf/3/  You can obviously add the accordion functionality later on.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.